# display the data of Controls Of JForm into JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, desktop-application

I have made an application in which a JForm containing the JTextfields,JButtons. When I click a button I want to display the data of JTextfield in JTable. How can I do this anybody help me. I know how the data from database is displayed in JTable. Now I work with controls..

Comment: *"I have made an application in which a JForm"*  There is no 'JForm' in the J2SE, and I don't speak Netbeans.  :(

Answer (score 2):

In the action event of jButton give,

```
jTable1.setValueAt(jTextField1.getText(), rowIndex,columnIndex);
```

Hope this may help you..